# why do I get an projects error when opening a project in unity 2020.3.12f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

when i open or create a progect in unity it says "cant find unity package manager local server application?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cweSE.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/33dbz.png

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straight forward.

Can you reinstall it with maybe the av off (or add an exception to the av).

You could also try a different version 2020.3.something else and see if it works.

Also check if you have proper read/write folder attributes where the unity files installs.